# How do you adjust image size to its container with css?

Tags: css

I have a logo on my website which lies in a specific grid-area.
I want it to be responsive in size and to maximum the respective grid-area.

I tried it with the following css, but it doesn't work:

```
.logo {
    grid-area: im;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo-img {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a link to the GitHub file: https://github.com/toniFET/WXApp.git

[print screen of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfVWo.png)

Comment: Does width: 100% not fill the space? Is that what you need?

Comment: No, with 50% it is already too big

Comment: Use `object-fit` perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a background image:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.grid > div {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  min-height:200px;
}

.grid > div.img{
  background-image:url(https://placekitten.com/200/200);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='img'></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did work. However I had to set background-size:contain;